# SQL Using GROUP BY with 2 Count Fields

Tags: sql, oracle, grouping

I am using SQL Developer and I'm trying to group a count of destination locations and a count of order volume for each origin location.  If I just group by origin location, the destination location count column doesn't group correctly.  It just copies the number of the order volume column.  For example I know that for 30746 there are supposed to be 6 destination locations instead of 66.  How do I remedy this?

```
ORIG_LOC    ORDER_CT    DEST_CT
30746             66    66
2293174           19    19
30760             17    17
2445576           28    28
2372979           18    18
2300026            3    3
2372983            4    4
2442988            1    1
30752             29    29
2526990            7    7
2522278           17    17
2300070           18    18
```

Comment: Please show the query you're using.

Comment: Also, some sample data would be nice.

Comment: Maybe... you just need to add distinct key word to your counts... `Select orig_loc, count(Distinct order_ct), count(Distinct dest_ct) From table group by Orig_loc` but your SQL would help define table structures involved. and sample data would be nice as FutbolFan said.

Comment: if I group by orig_loc and dest_loc I get the opposite problem: the dest_ct column shows the right valuea but order_ct now shows duplicate values of dest_ct.  There appears to be some sort of hierarchy to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some table structures would be nice, but it sounds like you want something like this:

```
SELECT orig_loc, COUNT(*) order_ct, COUNT(DISTINCT dest_loc) dest_ct
FROM order_table
GROUP BY orig_loc
```